# Controlling a treadmill motor

Tags: motor, driver

I'm recycling some spare parts of an old treadmill for a new project. I have the motor with its driver board, the elevator piston and the controller board. All works out of the box, but I need to replace the controller board with my own PIC-based since the former uC firmware cannot be modified, nor read (pretty obvious).

The controller schematic is pretty straight-forward, CON1 comes from the driver board, PIN1 is 19v, PIN2 is GND and the other two pins are connected as follow to the uC.

[image]

I measured the voltage at pins 3 and 4 with different speed/inclination  combinations obtaining always the same value (even stopped), around 4.8v on PIN3 and around 1v on PIN4. Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope so I can't see what's really going on there. I've had a look to the uC datasheet and the connected pins are just TTL output ports (it's a really old basic uC).

I've searched around the internet but I haven't found any similar board, so yeah, I'm wondering if someone has ever found/worked with this kind of driver.

Comment: did you check the controller pin which is connected with the base of Q1 then check the emitter voltage wrt ground by disconnecting the base connection(still if you get some voltage transistor may be leaky)

Comment: Umm, I'm getting unstable voltages, between 4.4 and 4.7 on pin 6 and 3.6-4 on pin 7, even when stopped. The speed/inclination don't seem to affect. My theory was that one pin controls the motor and the other the inclination piston, but I've disconnected one of the two pins separately (one pin each time) and it didn't work...so it looks like that the two pins are required, so I'm thinking that it may be a serial bus, one pin for data and the other for clock...I'll keep digging

Comment: You will probably need a scope, preferably a digital one with capture, as I think your serial bus hypothesis is true and it's SPI or I2C.